# What are these parts and elements in the schematic doing?

Tags: bridge

What are these transformers before the bridge? Whats the purpose at all of the schematics before the diode bridge?

[image]

Comment: where did you get this? a bit more info and context is needed.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please realise this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it, showing your work and findings so far in considerable detail. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Answer (score 10):

Looks like common mode chokes. It's a kind of transformer that is used to prevent current that flows in same direction on both wires. Why is it useful is a completely different story. Just call them a filter.

Comment: Gentlemen, you are kidding me. +9 for that? My best answers got much less

Comment: We all like simplicity. Olin would probably give us a 10 paragraph answer lol :)

Comment: Sime people probably is paid by pentagon or cia, otherwise i have no idea why would they type so much.